# Invalid attempt to read - Is possible using Action?

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

```
public void ExecuteAction(MySqlCommand query, Action<MySqlDataReader> action)
    {
        _connection.Open();
        query.Connection = _connection;
        using(var reader = query.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                action(reader);
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        _connection.Close();
    }
```

Is it possible to do something like this? I am getting always the error "Invalid attempt to Read when reader is closed".

This is a piece of code which I'm using:

```
private void UpdateRecords()
    {
        var query = String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", _table);
        var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query);
        _db.ExecuteAction(cmd, reader =>
                                   {
                                       var rows = new List<object>();
                                       for (var i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                                       {
                                           if (reader.IsDBNull(i)) continue;
                                           var name = reader.GetName(i);
                                           if (!_fields.Contains(name)) _fields.Add(name);
                                           rows.Add(reader.GetValue(i));
                                       }
                                       _records.Add(new Record(_fields, rows));
                                   });
    }
```

I'm trying to store all the records of a database's tables into dynamic classes inside the program. When I try to add dynamically mysql data into those classes I get this error.

Another question which is related: is there any library that can make this for me? It's a lot of code that I would not have to write down, but it is my first time approaching to MySQL and C#, so I don't have any type of knowledge.
Thanks for your help.

UPDATE: now I get the error that connection is already opened, MySQL is making me curse(I'm used to MongoDB...)

Comment: Instead of putting a "Solved" message at the top of your question, please add your solution as an answer that can be accepted and voted on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. I didn't know that I cannot use more than one time the same connection to call different readers, so I had to create a new one every time I need to query the db.

[MySQL - Multiple result sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321879/mysql-multiple-result-sets/3324656#3324656)

Answer (score 0):

Does `ExecuteAction` work? Are you even using that code? `UpdateRecords` has obvious problems. If you look at `ExecuteAction` it opens the connection then declares the reader within a `using` statement. After that it closes the connection. In `UpdateRecords` you have no code to handle opening/closing the connection and you're also missing code to dispose of the reader. As a result your code may work sometimes (like if the connection is already opened elsewhere) and will fail other times (in the case that the connection has not yet been made).

Comment: So maybe I'm missing something, but cannot I share a "default" connection throughout the classes to execute different queries? I have a class ServerConnection which, when initialized, connects to the database, and that connection should be the same every time I need to use it. So I open and close that connection creating every time a new reader and closing it when I finished. Now I am getting the error "commands out of sync". I really don't know what I'm wrong, and I can't find any type of documentation.

Comment: And yes, ExecuteAction works only for the first call, then I get an error(depending on I don't know what)